# UITableView delete section causes strange animation

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableView that is made up of sections with 1 row in each section. This is done so that I can get buffer space between each row. When the user deletes a row, they are de facto deleting the whole section.

My row deletion code in `commitEditingStyle` is:

```
[self.habitsToView removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[indexPath section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

But when a row is deleted, the animation is wrong. The row itself slides off to the left, and the delete button slides upwards. This happens no matter what value I use for `withRowAnimation`

Anyone know what could be causing the strange animation?

Comment: Strange. But you tried with  "[tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[indexPath section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];"
 ?

Comment: Yes. Every value of the animation enum causes the exact same effect, including `UITableViewRowAnimationNone`

Comment: Also try to add "[tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[indexPath section]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];" after "deleteSections".

Comment: And what is self.habitsToView?

Comment: That throws an error because it's trying to reload the same section that's being deleted.

Comment: `self.habitsToView` is an `NSMutableArray` with the data source for the table

Comment: You should also remove the data from the mutable array.